# WPF doesn't draw focus the button when focused programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I am writing a WPF GUI application using .NET 6.

I have a visual component structure similar to following:

```
<DockPanel>
<!-- .... some more components here.... -->
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="scv"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <DockPanel x:Name="pnl" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                </DockPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

The DockPanel will contain some buttons created programmatically. I'm using custom focus style for those buttons, just a simple solid black border. For that I've added following Style definition:

```xml
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusStyle" TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

I am creating buttons like this:

```cs
        _buttonFocusStyle = (Style)FindResource("ButtonFocusStyle");
        // ....
        var button = new Button()
        {
            Name = $"btn{_nextButtonId++}",
            Content = "some text on the button",
            Background = Brushes.Transparent,
            BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent,
            FocusVisualStyle = _buttonFocusStyle,
            Tag = "something"
        };
        button.Click += Button_Click;
        pnl.Children.Add(button);
```

Then, I want to focus a button programmatically. For that, at some point, I'm doing following:

```cs
    Activate();
    firstButton.Focus();
```

where `firstButton` is a first button created. But with this, neither default, nor my custom focus border is drawn. However, when I press right arrow key, focus does move to a next button, my custom focus rectangle is correctly drawn on it. Then, when I press left arrow key, and focus moves back to the button that I've initially focused programmatically, and the custom focus rectangle is correctly removed from focused "next" button and correctly drawn on the "first" button.

From this, I make conclusion that when I've done the `firstButton.Focus()`, "firstButton" actually have received the focus, but for some reason focus rectangle was not drawn. Can someone please explain and advise, why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/focus-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-6.0

Comment: Have you tried Keyboard.Focus method? FocusVisualStyle requires keyboard focus.

Comment: The `Focus()` method has a boolean return value, that indicates whether keyboard focus could be successfully gained; in this case it returns `true`. If only logical focus or none at all could be set, it returns `false`.
You could check that return value, when you call `firstButton.Focus()` to narrow down the issue. The most likely assumption is that the button just gains logical focus, and only by UI interaction also keyboard focus.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.focus?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks

Comment: Try Keyboard.Focus(firstButton);

Comment: Keyboard.Focus(firstButton) same effect gives just the same effect